# Send node file attachment on form submit

Tags: nodes, emails

I have a form built into a block on one of my content types, the content type has a file connected to the node.

I currently have a form the will send an email to the address you put in with a default message (ie if you put into the form, me@myemail.com, this email will receive a message saying "thank you for your interest.. ..please find your document attached" etc) However I'm struggling when it comes to attaching the file attachment of that node to the form, I have downloaded the mimemail module but there isn't a lot of documentation on how to do it.

Any help would be great,

Kind regards

Comment: You mean you need to send email with attachment?

Comment: Yes, I already have the form set up that emails you, but I want to make it attach the file from the node to it